# rails difference between Model.count and Model.count(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any difference between

```
User.count
```

and

```
User.count(:all)
```

I upgraded rails to 4.0 then when I use `ModelName.count(:all)` it's working well but if I use `ModelName.count` the following error occurs.By the way bot of them is working well in rails 3.2

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM "users"
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  count(*) must be used to call a parameterless aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT() FROM "users"
```

Comment: I don't have such error in rails4 using Model.count. What's weird in your example is that it's trying to execute select count() insteand of select count(*). Have you tried User.all.count ?

Comment: Result:SELECT COUNT() FROM "users"
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  count(*) must be used to call a parameterless aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT() FROM "users"

Comment: and what does output User.all?

Comment: User.all works. result = > SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<user1>,#<user2>]

Comment: What about `User.all.count` ?

Comment: You seem to have something installed (a gem perhaps?) that is overriding the default `count` behavior - can you trace the call to see where this may be happening?

Comment: We are using rails4.0-stable.Maybe it is about rails version?

Comment: I changed rails version to 4.0.0 from 4.0.0-stable then the problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue as well. The change was introduced in **[this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/da9b5d4a8435b744fcf278fffd6d7f1e36d4a4f2)**. A line like

```
User.count
```

will now throw an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error since it will generate `SELECT COUNT() FROM users` on Postgres. As of this commit, the fix is to update your code to

```
User.count(:all)
```

**[This commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/648afea0e4addcaaf6da31cba78b94d7681706a4)** restores the functionality that existed previously, using `:all` as the  "column" to pass on to ARel, causing a valid SQL query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users`.

My `Gemfile` originally had the following *(as mentioned in the comments)*

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "4-0-stable"
```

but I needed to run `bundle update rails` to pull down the newer commit referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no difference between them

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

> By not passing any parameters to count, it will return a count of all the rows for the model.